# Comparing User IP with .txt file content

Tags: php

I have a .txt file which contains about 100.000 IP's (Blacklisted), I want to check if the current user IP is present in that .txt file, if yes script execution should stop.

What would be the most efficient way to do this without using .htaccess.

Comment: Please post the code you've already tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ban IPs from text file using htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008242/ban-ips-from-text-file-using-htaccess)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Block 100,000+ Individual IP addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15579620)

Comment: I'm not using .htaccess

Comment: Are you using a database?

Comment: How so ? This Answer explains how I could use that text file with a .htaccess, which I said I'm not using ?

Comment: So, you're not actually asking for the "most efficient way" after all?

Comment: I did, with the addition in the comment that I'm not using .htaccess ? :-)

Comment: Then please consider reading through the dozens of duplicates we already have on this topic: http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20block%20ip%20from%20text%20file

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Block 100,000+ Individual IP addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579620/how-to-block-100-000-individual-ip-addresses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file = file_get_contents( "your_text_file.txt" );
if( preg_match( "/$ip/", $file ) ) {
  // block
}
```

If you're going to block using preg_match you may want to add the newline to the search string and escape the period characters because otherwise they will match any single character ( however unlikely, this may block normal users ). Htaccess is much better suited for this or even a database query.

Comment: This will also match on near same IP's or ? I mean, if I have 127.0.0.12 in the ban list, and my IP is 127.0.0.1  it will also block ?

Comment: If each IP address is on a new line add \n to the end of the search string for example "/127\.0\.0\.12\n/" you can use str_replace to swap out the "." characters for "\."

Comment: Thanks, in the meantime I found this: `if( preg_match( "#\b{$ip}\b#", $file )`

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are going to store the data will help you to lookup faster. Keeping the data into the sorted format and then try to do the binary search kind of thing help you to search the thing faster. I am just suggesting the theory part :)