# Best way to allow access to members area by IP via PHP or HTACCESS or something else?

Tags: php, .htaccess, ip, membership

I would like to know if allowing access to a membership area would be more efficient by htaccess allow or a PHP array of ips to check against every page.  I am mainly interested in performance.

Are either of these methods recommended when your dealing with hundreds or even thousands of ips?

Is there a better way?

Update:

What if i sniffed for IP and then depending on if the IP is recognized I start a membership or none membership session so as to not have to check ip every pageview?

Comment: Considering IP addresses can be spoofed rather easily, that seems like a bad idea...

Comment: unfortunately i need some access by ip

Answer (score 3):

It's probably quicker to use htaccess since you won't need to run the php handler to run your php script. There's a similar answer that I gave [for **blocking** IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580768/851273) which utilizes the `RewriteMap`. You'd just need something the other way around, instead of denying access from those IPs, grant access:

```
RewriteMap allow_ips txt:/path/to/allow_ips.txt

RewriteCond ${allow_ips:%{REMOTE_ADDR}|0} =1
RewriteRule ^protected/path - [L]

RewriteRule ^protected/path - [L,F]
```

The contents of the allow_ips .txt file would be:

```
12.34.56.78 1
11.22.33.44 1
etc.
```

The `RewriteMap` directed *must be in either the server or vhost config*. You can define a map from htaccess, though you can use it there.

If you can't use maps, then you'll need to enumerate all the IPs with an `Allow`. In the htaccess file in the directory you want to protect:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
Allow from 12.34.56.78
Allow from 11.22.33.44
...
```

> Is there a better way?

The best way is probably to implement a user/password via htpasswd. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess3.shtml). Then you can put the `Auth*` stuff in an htaccess file in the directory you want to protect and that's that. Simple.

Comment: This is interesting. Could there be any performance advantage/distadvantage with the rewitemap over the way tapas pal describes below? Or maybe its just more oragnized.

Comment: Unfortunelty i dont have access to the server/vhost config so i may not be able to use this method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use .htaccess

```
<Files 403.shtml>
   order deny,allow
   deny from all
</Files>

allow from 142.4.98.37
allow from 193.105.210.217
allow from 142.4.98.35

//Allow those ip which you want
```

Comment: I currently do it this way. Was wonderinh the pros and cons of this way vs the PHP way of checking for IP every page view

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with more than a hundred of I.P. addresses, specially a dynamic I.P., of course the best way to allowing the access, is via PHP script, such like this! Remember that this code is just an example and not completely reviewed:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] != $row['ip']) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
        break;
    }
}
```

Viewers can do the rest to fix the syntax above, that's why it's in **community wiki**.

### About the Advantages

For me, there are many advantages in a server-side scripting language. Such you can even program the application to **automatically block** the I.P. addresses of the users that are spamming, and you can even program how long will they be blocked.

Comment: Right. Thanks but i am aware of how to do it the php way and htaccess way. I was hoping for some insight into WHY which way is better. Why do you say PHP would be better after 100 ips?

Comment: @chris _“About the Advantages”_ added.