# Redirecting 400 URLs with Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

I need to permanently redirect about 400 URLs. What's the best way to go about it? The most obvious solution would be to add 400 lines of "Redirect 301 old-url new-url" to .htaccess. Is there a better way?

Example URLs:

**50 of these:**

```
/category -> /new-category-name-c/
```

**about 350 of these:**

```
/category/subcategory/product.html -> /slightly-different-product-name.html
```

Edit: added example

Comment: You can use regular expression.. Can you post an example of old and new URLs?

Comment: @pandronic: There are ways to avoid writing 400 Rewrite rules but you need to tell us specific details like a small sample of old and new URLs.

Comment: I've added a generic example. We've completely redone a badly done website, changed a lot of the product and category names so there's no obvious pattern between the old and the new URLs. Thanks.

Comment: Check this [answer from Jon Lin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579620/how-to-block-100-000-individual-ip-addresses/15580768#15580768)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a PHP(or any other) script which will handle all pages which does not exist. It will detect the old URLs and return 301 redirect to new URL.

If old URLs cannot be parsed by regexp, you will need to create a map, like this:

```
$urlMap = array(
    '/category1' => '/new-category1',
    '/category2' => '/new-category2'
);
```

and to look up the new URLs from it. If URL is not in map, then return 404 header or redirect to somewhere else..

You can use the `ErrorDocument` directive to define custom 404 page:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /process-urls.php
```

You can get the path from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

#### Update

As suggested by @faa, you can use the [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) apache directive. You need to create a *txt* file which will map from old URLs to new ones, one mapping per row, space separated:

```
/category1 /new-category-1
/category2 /new-category-2
```

Then, in your **virtual host file**, declare the map:

```
RewriteMap examplemap txt:/path/to/file/map.txt
```

And the rewrite rule(may be placed in *.htaccess*):

```
RewriteCond ${examplemap:%{REQUEST_URI}|0} !=0
RewriteRule ^(.*) ${examplemap:$1|/not_found.html}
```

This method is easier to maintain than putting 400 rewrite rules to *.htaccess*.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid scripting. Would it affect performance badly if I were to add 400 lines of "Redirect 301"?

Comment: @pandronic I think it will affect performance, but don't know to what extent..

Comment: +1 The problem could be with the queries when using mod_alias. I think any of your options is a better solution.