# Apache dynamic whitelist

Tags: apache, web, apache2, www-authenticate

I am looking for a solution for dynamic whitelist, so I do not need to restart apache2 service. I've tried to do something like this:

```
order Deny,Allow
include conf/IPList.conf
Allow from all
```

But this solution didnt work for me correctly. I've tried also this, but im not sure if my whitelist.txt is correct. How should it looks like?

```
## WHITELIST IPS ##
RewriteMap ipslist txt:/path/to/whitelist.txt
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond ${ipslist:%1|black} ^black$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [F]
```

Or maybe there is another, better way to make dynamic whitelist for Apache2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a rewrite map is fine. There's a reverse way to do this that I've posted about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580768/851273).

You can simplify the rules a little though:

```
RewriteMap ipslist txt:/path/to/whitelist.txt

RewriteCond ${ipslist:%{REMOTE_ADDR}|black} ^black$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The whitelist.txt file needs to look like:

```
1.2.3.4 ok
2.3.4.5 ok
```

etc.

The "ok" can be anything, but you need something that the whitelisted IP address maps to, other than "black". The whitelist.txt file will be cached by apache and when you change it, apache will automatically reload and reparse the file. This way, you don't need to restart apache.

Comment: I've insterted your solution just after directory tag, but it still allows other IPs to enter the website. Do i need htaccess file or something like that?

<Directory /var/www/>
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

         RewriteMap ipslist txt:/home/slawek/whitelist.txt
         RewriteCond ${ipslist:%{REMOTE_ADDR}|black} ^black$ [NC]
         RewriteRule ^ - [F]

Comment: Ok, problem solved. It didn't work just becouse of routing problems. Thanks for help!